# Android socket programming approach

Tags: android, sockets

I am making a client socket program in Android, it sends and receive data correctly, but my problem is the client is running in the "doInBackground" of the Asyntask. I need the info the client receives from the server in order to continue with rest the processes, and there is my question and the approach I need, how I make the program wait until the client socket method receives the data before calling the others methods?

Example :

1)
MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(server, port);
myClientTask.execute();

2) Do_something_with _data_received();

3) Do_something_else_with _data_received();

The point 2  will run with the client socket at the same time in this approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't "make the program wait". Call the dependent methods once the data has been received.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a fragment pass the fragment to the asynctask.
Do the logic in doInBackground() then fragment.method() in onPostExecute().

onPreexecute and onPostExecute run on the UI thread, doInBackground() runs on a separate thread.

Hint: you could replace the view with a progress(circular) untill asynctask is done,

```
onPostExecute(){
    if(fragment.isAdded()){
       fragment.drawUI();
    }
}
```

where the drawUI() is the logic that makes your layoutView and makes it visible.

```
onPostExecute(){

2) Do_something_with _data_received();

3) Do_something_else_with _data_received();

}
```

TIP : Don't call .get() of asynctask because it will freeze UI thread.